# How to generate a hashcode from object with two list containing the same type of objects

Tags: java, list, hashcode

Let's say I have a class (the equal method also exists):

```
public class SomeClassA {
    private int a;
    private int b;

        @Override
 public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + a;
    result = prime * result + b;
    return result;
 }
}
```

And another class:

```
public class SomeClassB {
  List<SomeClassA> firstList;
  List<SomeClassA> secondList;
```

How do I construct the hashcode so that two objects are seen as equals if they have the same objects in firstList and the same objects in secondList.

//Hank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + firstList.hashCode();
    result = prime * result + secondList.hashCode();
    return result;
 }
```

Comment: Will this approach return the same value if I switch the objects in the two lists? I don't want that.

Comment: It depends what you mean when say "if they have the same objects in firstList and the same objects in secondList" If same elements in different order means not equal thats right. If not just convert lists to Set before hashcode calculation

Comment: List(1, 2, 3).equals(List(3, 2, 1)) will return false (and different hashcodes). Set(1, 2, 3).equals(Set(3, 2, 1)) will return true (and same hashcodes)

Comment: Have you override equals method? just post it and i will say is my hashcode correct or not. Dont forget that you should override equals if you have overrided hashcode and vice versa

Comment: Yes! I have. Guess I have to implement a set instead :/

Comment: there is all information that you need to make correct hashcode and equals methods: Joshua Bloch. Effective Java, Chapter 3